# Solaris 11.3 can't import a pool

Tags: sata, solaris, zfs, sas

I had some reboots last days and guess it's something to do with the SAS controller. But maybe I'm wrong.

Any idea why the `zpool import` and `zdb -e [pool]` aborted or crashed with core dumps?

Failure message is:

> Assertion failed: range != 0, file ../../../uts/common/fs/zfs/spa_misc.c, line 1326, function spa_get_random

The SAS controller is a 9221-8i in IT mode and the disks are connected via SATA, 
but those are not detected via a direct SATA connection...

Comment: Looks like a bug. The assertion that's failing looks like [this one](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/4417096956f7439322c65d9e70a4526df45ea8d0/module/zfs/spa_misc.c#L1413). If you can get a full backtrace you might be able to submit a bug report to Oracle. I'm not sure what you can do to bypass this yourself, though.

Comment: Is the `zpool import ...` process crashing?  Or is the entire system crashing with a kernel panic?  If the entire system is crashing, the backtrace should be logged in `/var/adm/messages`.